# IntelliJ IDEA - Maven Repository glitch?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

OK, I should put everything in simple explanation:
When I try to add new Java library from Maven, I do everything as normal, but in the "Download Library from Maven Repository", after the spinning dotted circle finishes animating, I get no result. For example
 When I try to find HttpClient library in the group org.apache.httpcomponents, if I only search for HttpClient or httpcomponents:HttpClient, no result is found for that library. It's found if only I search the whole groupID, and narrow down the search with library name. Moreover, the version appears, they are not always the latest version.

 On the other hand, it does get some library like NekoHTML.

 Import manually by adding to pom.xml works well. But I'm actually not in good term with XML, my vision just cannot apprehend the XML view.

Answer (score 0):

There is related issue on YouTrack:  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-179857. As a workaround you could use "HttpClient" as a search string

Comment: Actually, as I described, I did search HttpClient as a search string.
<br>
Tried with Eclipse, same thing seems to happen but in different manner: Any search string less then 7(except special character like -) won't trigger searching in repo. For example: "spring", "spring-". While springf (as in springframework) or spring-w(as for spring-web) did result in a lof of result